# Как верно выбрать атрибуты для fopen()

Tags: c, файлы, fopen

Помогите выбрать атрибуты:

1. Открытие или создание файла (если не создан) для чтения [без перезаписи]
2. Открытие или создание файла (если не создан) для записи [с перезаписью]
3. Открытие или создание файла (если не создан) для чтения и записи [без перезаписи, только дополнение]

Пытался "заGOOGLEить", но понял, что запутался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забавно - какой смысл в создании пустого файла для чтения? :)

- 1 - просто `"r"`, но создаваться новый не будет - бессмысленно...
- 2 - `"w"`
- 3 - `"a+"`

См. [красивую табличку](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen)